# SQL change number format to custom "0000000000000000" from any integer number in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying write a SQL SELECT statement in Snowflake where I need to select a column 'xyz' form table 'a'(select xyz from a). Although, the number in column xyz is formatted into 6,7,8 digits and I want to convert that in select statement itself to 16 digits with leading 0's. I used concat() but since the column contains either 6,7,8 digits I am not able to format it into max 16 digits with leading 0's.

Note: I need it to be in select statement as I cant update the column in the database to 16 digit format.

Example

```
Input: 123456, 1234567, 12345678
Output should be: 0000000000123456, 0000000001234567, 0000000012345678
```

Can someone help me out here please. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) won't work?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Using [TO_VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html) with format provided:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(12345, '0000000000000000');
```

---

```
WITH cte(c) AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES (123456), (1234567),(12345678))
)
SELECT c, TO_VARCHAR(c, '0000000000000000') AS result
FROM cte;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: select some_column, TO_VARCHAR (some_column,'0000000000000000') from "xyz"

gives me an error "too many arguments for function". I need to select those values from a column (some_column) from a table (xyz). Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic width, or to stick to a form of CONCAT then here are some extra ways.

```
SELECT column1,
    TO_CHAR(column1, '0000000000000000') as fixed_width,  
    TO_CHAR(column1, REPEAT('0', 16)) as dynamic_width,
    RIGHT(REPEAT('0', 16) || column1::text, 16) as another_way,
    LPAD(column1, 16, '0')
FROM VALUES 
    (123456), 
    (1234567),
    (12345678),
    (12345.678),
    (1234567890123456789)
```

| COLUMN1 | FIXED_WIDTH | DYNAMIC_WIDTH | ANOTHER_WAY | LPAD(COLUMN1, 16, '0') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123,456 | 0000000000123456 | 0000000000123456 | 000000123456.000 | 000000123456.000 |
| 1,234,567 | 0000000001234567 | 0000000001234567 | 000001234567.000 | 000001234567.000 |
| 12,345,678 | 0000000012345678 | 0000000012345678 | 000012345678.000 | 000012345678.000 |
| 12,345.678 | 0000000000012346 | 0000000000012346 | 000000012345.678 | 000000012345.678 |
| 1,234,567,890,123,456,789 | ################ | ################ | 890123456789 | 1234567890123456 |

the two TO_CHAR/TO_VARCHAR methods don't deal with floating results, where-as the RIGHT version does. But that doesn't handle values that are larger the 16 DP

### Using you SQL

So using the SQL you put in your comment, and then using 2 CTE's for fake out some data AND using one of the many answers to your question, we get:

```
WITH "abc" as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (123456),
        (1234567)
        t(ki)
), "xyz" as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (6, 123456),
        (7, 1234567)
    t(ki_value, piv_id)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    y.kI, 
    yo.ki_value, 
    yo.piv_num 
FROM "abc" as y 
left join (
    select 
        ki_value, 
        LPAD(piv_id, 16, '0') as piv_num 
        --concat('0000000000',piv_id) as piv_num 
    from "xyz"
) as yo on y.KI = yo.piv_num 
WHERE y.KI in (123456,1234567)
```

this gives:

```
KI  |KI_VALUE   |PIV_NUM
--|--|--
123,456 |6  |0000000000123456
1,234,567   |7  |0000000001234567
```

So this "works" but as your SQL is written, it's really bad. The WHERE statement is checking the values are numbers and are in the range, why on earth are you want to string pad numbers as TEXT with however many number of zeros in front, because you should leave them as numbers.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT  y.kI, yo.ki_value, yo.piv_num
FROM "abc" as y
left join (select ki_value, concat('0000000000',piv_id) as piv_num from "xyz") as yo
on y.KI = yo.piv_num
WHERE y.KI in (123456,1234567)         \\\\\  \\\ \ \\ \ \\ 


THis is my Query, I dont want to use concat because it wont join for "1234567" as concat will make it 17 digits instead of 16 digits with leading 0's. I am not too sure about nested queries hence couldn't figure out how to use your solution on this. Main goal is to join on y.KI = yo.piv_num and pull in all Ki_values from that table.

Comment: @YashAmbavade well you code as it stand will return zero values, as you are making a string 16 chars wide to join, and then requiring it to be one of two numbers that is 6 or 7. Anyways, I was assume you where doing some for of presentation formatting. so presented some results.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(c) as (
    select * FROM (
        values (12345), (293848238), (284), (239432043223432)
    )
)
select lpad(c, 16, '0') as c from data;

+------------------+
| C                |
|------------------|
| 0000000000012345 |
| 0000000293848238 |
| 0000000000000284 |
| 0239432043223432 |
+------------------+
```